# Working with text in pdfkit

Tags: javascript, node-pdfkit

How to set characterSpacing from pt/px?

How to set lineHeight from pt/px?

I just can not understand how to translate from points or pixels into a value for pdfkit. Help me please

https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit

---

I need to convert html text to pdf. And you need to match the letter spacing and the line spacing.

> CSS: Font - 18pt; LineHeight - 1.4 (not pt); letterSpacing - 2pt;

How to set this in pdfkit?

```
doc.text(element.content, element.left, element.top, {
     width            : element.width,
     align            : element.properties.textAlign,       
     characterSpacing : 2, //???
     lineBreak        : false,
     lineGap          : 1.4, //????
 });
```

Comment: show us some code, what you have already tried

Answer (score 2):

When using pdfKit, measurements are in points where 72 points is 1 inch.
So characterSpacing is how many "points" between each character. In the example provided of 2, it would be 2 points or 2/72 of an inch.

The lineGap, is the number of points between lines of text. For example, lineGap: 10 is 10/72 of an inch. This represents the space between the bottom of one row and the top of the subsequent row.

This is different than line-height in HTML, where line-height is more like a multiplier of the specified line height.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it works for me, I hope it helps someone

```
doc
  .fontSize(10)
  .font('Helvetica-Bold')
  .lineGap(5)
  .text('your text', 50, 50, { align: 'right' }); 
// positioning of your text first 50 is for x, second for y
```